# Javascript Closures

Tags: javascript, function, closures

So I created a variable car and then assigned it to a function and added the arguments model, year. Then created an object within the function with reference to the arguments.

Then Created the "closure" inner function yourCar() and returned the outer functions object "Properties" within it. followed by returning the inner function yourCar() within the outer function to be available on a global scope.

So to my understanding I thought the inner function has access to all of the variables and functions to the outer function. Thus I called yourCar(model, year); to get the object variables.

But keep getting the error message :
"yourCar is not defined"... I am using scratchpad on mozilla fox to test and debug. Can anyone help with this, so I can understand it a bit better!

```
 var car = function(model, year){
    var Properties = {
       model: nissan,
       year: 2004
    }
    function yourCar() {
        return Properties;
    }

    return yourCar();
 }
 yourCar(model, year);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like both said, you're trying to reach a private method on the wrong object.

here's a JSBIN demo: http://jsbin.com/acohoYUP/2/edit?js,console

Mainly holding:

```
var car = function(model, year){
  var Properties = {
    model: "nissan",
    year: 2004
  };
  function yourCar() {
    return Properties;
  }

 return yourCar();
};

var updatedCar = function(model, year){
  var Properties = {
    model: model,
    year: year
  };
  function yourCar() {
    return Properties;
  }

  return yourCar();
};

var badCar = car("lemon", 1999);
var goodCar = updatedCar("ferrari", 2014);
```

You can see that the stats on `badCar` will be `nissan` and `2004`, instead of the parameters passed (using `badCar.year` for example).

On the `goodCar`, like **pswg** suggested, they are correct.

Answer (score 2):

`yourCar` is defined inside `car`. Only the functions and variables insider `car` can access `yourCar`. It is kind of private to the `car` function. So, you cannot access it outside. You should be actually calling `car`, like this

```
car (model, year);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `yourCar` as a function only within the scope of `car` (or more accurately, the anonymous function bound to `car`). So outside of `car`, `yourCar` doesn't mean anything; it's undefined.

It looks like you were trying to do something like this:

```
var car = function(model, year){
    var Properties = {
       model: model,
       year: year
    };
    function yourCar() {
        return Properties;
    }

    return yourCar();
}
var result = car('nissan', 2004);
```

Comment: Exactly! When I placed it in scratchpad like so...  result;  I got model: "nissan" year:2004  but it came up with _proto_: Object  right under it on the side panel. of the debugger, I am guessing it must be showing its inheritance protocol from car?